# ¿Como lanzar otra actividad al hacer click en cardview?

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio

Tengo un `Recyclerview` con `Cardview`s que muestran una imagen y una descripción corta que se obtiene a través de un `JSON`(con `volley`), lo que quiero es que, al hacer click en algún item del recycler se abra toda la información junto con la imagen pero no se como, no se si usar una actividad o un fragmento y obviamente cada item debe abrir su respectiva descripción

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    RequestQueue queue;
    String url = "http://urljson";
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List<NewsFeed> feedsList = new ArrayList<NewsFeed>();
    MyRecyclerAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //initialize toolbar
        mToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        //Initialize RecyclerView
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        adapter = new MyRecyclerAdapter(this, feedsList);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        //Scroll-hide
        recyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new MyScrollListener(this) {
            @Override
            public void onMoved(int distance) {
                mToolbar.setTranslationY(-distance);
            }
            //Scroll-hide
        });
        //Getting Instance of Volley Request Queue
        queue = NetworkController.getInstance(this).getRequestQueue();
        //Volley's inbuilt class to make Json array request
        JsonArrayRequest newsReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {

                        JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        NewsFeed feeds = new NewsFeed(obj.getString("title"), obj.getString("content"), obj.getString("image"));

                        // adding movie to movies array
                        feedsList.add(feeds);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    } finally {
                        //Notify adapter about data changes
                        adapter.notifyItemChanged(i);
                    }
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                System.out.println(error.getMessage());
            }
        });
        //Adding JsonArrayRequest to Request Queue
        queue.add(newsReq);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

**AdaptadorRecycler**

```
public class MyRecyclerAdapter extends    RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<NewsFeed> feedsList;
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MyRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<NewsFeed> feedsList) {

        this.context = context;
        this.feedsList = feedsList;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.singleitem_recyclerview, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(rootView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        NewsFeed feeds = feedsList.get(position);
        //Pass the values of feeds object to Views
        holder.title.setText(feeds.getFeedName());
        holder.content.setText(feeds.getContent());
        holder.imageview.setImageUrl(feeds.getImgURL(), NetworkController.getInstance(context).getImageLoader());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return feedsList.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView content, title;
        private NetworkImageView imageview;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_view);
            content = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.content_view);
            // Volley's NetworkImageView which will load Image from URL
            imageview = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "msg msg", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es añadir un `ItemTouchListener` al `RecyclerView` para capturar los click y cuando pulses sobre un elemento se abra una nueva `Activity`

```
 final GestureDetector mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(LibrosActivity.this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {           
     @Override public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
          return true;
     } 
 });

recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean b) {

            }

            @Override
            public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                try {
                    View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());

                    if (child != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)) {

                        int position = recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(child);

                        NewsFeed n = feedsList.get(position);

                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivitity.this, PantallaInformacion.class);
                        intent.putExtra("news", (Serializable) n); //por si quieres pasarle el objeto a la nueva actividad, tendrás que hacerlo serializable
//                      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                        startActivity(intent);

                        return true;
                    }
                }catch (Exception e){
//                  e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            }
        });
```

Luego en la nueva actividad que crees puedes hacer:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            finish();
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
       if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)  {
           finish();
           return true;
       }

        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event); 
    }
```

Para volver a tu `MainActivity` desapilando la nueva actividad y quedándose la lista de elementos como estaba antes de clickar.

De esta forma podrás mostrar toda la información que desees en una Actividad para cada item que se pulse.

Espero te sirva de ayuda.